# Show error from Share Extension

Tags: ios, swift, ios8-share-extension

I'm developing a Share Extension for my iOS app where the user can upload a picture to our service. As the image can be quite large, I'm doing the upload in the background.

The problem is that sometimes there can be an error when uploading the image (network is down, our service is unavailable at the moment, the server detects something incorrect in the image,...) but I don't know how to tell this to the user, as I don't have a window, So I can't show a UIAlertView or something similar.

What would be the best way to alert the user that the upload hasn't finished completely?